Do Federal Agencies have to abide by D.C. local laws?
Many (but not all) U.S. federal agencies are headquartered in the District of Columbia (D.C.).  D.C. has a unique legal situation amongst U.S. cities that is some mix of city-like and state-like authority.  In this context, D.C. is authorized to pass various types of laws applicable within its jurisdiction.  This includes certain types of laws governing entities (e.g. businesses) operating within D.C.  Do the U.S. federal government agencies operating within D.C. generally have to abide by these D.C.-specific laws?
For example, D.C. recently passed a law banning employment discrimination based on housing status.  This law is not at the federal level, it is a local D.C. law.  Does this law affect federal agencies based in D.C.?  If so, does it apply to the entire agency, since they are headquartered in D.C., or only to employees whose duty station is within the D.C. city limits?  More generally, how do these sorts of laws affect federal agencies headquartered in D.C.?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
